# ArcGIS Monitor 2023.2 Unsupported SSL Issue

Tags: arcgis-enterprise

Trying to install and configure ArcGIS Monitor 2023.2, I am facing with unsupported error message when uploading our certificate file in .pfx  format

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening and what is the proper format for uploading SSL into ArcGIS Monitor?

Comment: This is a question that I think is best submitted to Esri's Technical Support.